# ¿Cómo hacer la suma de dos imagenes en Java?

Tags: java

He estado tratando de realizar la suma de dos imagenes en java,ya pude 
acceder a los RGB de cada imagen, al igual que hacer la suma entre las 
mismas, lo que ahora obtengo es un resultado en escala de grises, alguien 
me podría indicar por qué pasa eso? Aquí adjunto parte del código que 
estoy utilizando.

//De esta forma obtengo el rgb de la primera imagen mediante el método getRGB(), de igual forma obtengo el RGB de la segunda imagen en 3 arreglos bidimensionales llamados: R1[][], G1[][] Y B1[][].

```
Color color_aux;
R = new int [ancho][altura];
G = new int [ancho][altura];
B = new int [ancho][altura];

for(int i= 0; i<ancho; i++)
{
for(int j= 0; j<altura; j++)
{
color_aux = new Color(imagen_original.getRGB(i, j));
R [i][j] = color_aux.getRed();
G [i][j] = color_aux.getGreen();
B [i][j] = color_aux.getBlue();
}
}
```

//Y en la siguiente porción de código hago la suma de las dos imagenes:

```
TRANSFORMADA = new int [ancho][altura];
for(int i= 0; i<ancho; i++)
{
for(int j= 0; j<altura; j++)
{
TRANSFORMADA[i][j] = (int) ((R[i][j] + R1[i][j])/2);
TRANSFORMADA[i][j] = (int) ((G[i][j] + G1[i][j])/2);
TRANSFORMADA[i][j] = (int) ((B[i][j] + B1[i][j])/2);
}
}
```

//Y por último, guardo la imagen ya transformada:

```
try
{
imagen_trabajada = new BufferedImage(x, y, imagen_original.getType());
for(int i = 0; i<Imagen.length; i++)
{
for(int j = 0; j<Imagen[0].length; j++)
{
int rgb  = Imagen[i][j] << 16 | Imagen[i][j] <<8 | Imagen[i][j];
imagen_trabajada.setRGB(i, j, new Color(rgb).getRGB());
}

}
}catch(Exception e) {System.out.println(e);}
}
```

@Juan Rom

Comment: Hola, debes mostrar una porción de código

Comment: `int[] rgb =new int[3];// posición 0: rojo, 1: verde, 2: azul; Color naranja =new Color(255, 102, 0);` Para guardar naranja: `rgb[0] =naranja.getRed(); rgb[1] =naranja.getGreen(); rgb[2] =naranja.getBlue();` Ahora para sumarle el rgb de un colorX: `rgb[0] +=colorX.getRed(); rgb[1] +=colorX.getGreen(); rgb[2] +=colorX.getBlue()`. El problema es que la suma no debe superar el valor 255, por que cada `int` tiene un rango del 0 al 255

Comment: Hola Juan Rom, gracias por contestar a la brevedad posible. Disculpa si no puse una porción de código. Te comento que ya pude acceder al RGB de las imagenes y guardarlas en arreglos bidimensionales para posteriormente realizar operaciones básicas entre ellas, lo que no entiendo, es por qué las operaciones me salen en escala de grises. Pongo una parte del código:

Comment: Hola @Eduard YM ¡bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Te sugiero hacer el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para poder ayudarte de la mejor manera. ¿Puedes EDITAR tu pregunta y agregar el código con el que tenias problemas?

Comment: Disculpa, ya he modificado la pregunta para ajustarla a como debe ser, saludos y gracias.